# Running conditional builds on gcloud app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

I have the following in my `cloudbuild.yml` file

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
  args: ['install', 'app']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy', 'app/${_GAE_APP_YAML}.yaml']

#Following will deploy only if the branch is develop to avoid having two testnet environments
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    [[ "$BRANCH_NAME" == "develop" ]] && gcloud app deploy app/${_GAE_APP_TESTNET_YAML}.yaml
timeout: 1800s
```

Basically, I want the first and the second step to execute everytime. However, I want the third step to execute only if the `BRANCH_NAME=develop`

All the steps run successfully if `BRANCH_NAME=develop`. However, when I commit to `master` (BRANCH_NAME is not develop), I get the following error:

```
Finished Step #1
Starting Step #2
Step #2: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Finished Step #2
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: exit status 1
```

I tried to login to the container on my local and test it like this

```
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
root@ac7edd78bea4:/# export BRANCH_NAME=develop
root@ac7edd78bea4:/# echo $BRANCH_NAME
develop
root@ac7edd78bea4:/# [[ "$BRANCH_NAME" == "develop" ]] && echo "kousgubh"
kousgubh
/# [[ "$BRANCH_NAME" == "ddfevelop" ]] && echo "kousgubh" //Doesn't print anything
```

So, the condition seems fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there's a better way to do this, though I can't think of it at the moment.

A quick-n-dirty answer to your question is to invert the logic a bit:

```
[[ "$BRANCH_NAME" != "develop" ]] || gcloud app deploy app/${_GAE_APP_TESTNET_YAML}.yaml
```

This works because when `$BRANCH_NAME == "develop"`, the first expression evaluates to true and the second expression is not run (`||` is a short-circuiting `OR`).  When `$BRANCH_NAME != "develop"`, the first expression is false, so the second expression is evaluated.